Arm pointer authentication keys A and B on Apple M1 and M3
On macOS 14 Sonoma, the management of pointer authentication keys is different on Apple M1 and Apple M3 systems. The pointer authentication (PAC) is a hardware feature. The PAC key management is a software feature. This is why I do not understand why the operating system manages them differently depending on the CPU. Any idea on this?
Brief recap on PAC:

There are 4 main PAC keys, IA, AB, DA, DB, "I" for instruction, "D" for data, key A and key B in both cases.
On macOS and Linux, Arm64 architecture, each new process receives a new set of 4 random PAC keys. This is a security feature. Reusing a signed pointer from a process X inside a process Y does not work. I have seen this on all recent Arm64 chips so far, including Apple M1.

I just got a new iMac M3 and noticed that the A keys do not change across processes.
On the same version of the macOS operating system. On the M3, the keys IA and DA never change, while the keys IB and DB expectedly change on each process. I do not understand the reason for this. Any idea?
The two systems are a MacBook M1 and an iMac M3. They both run macOS 14.4.1, build 23E224.
The kernels are sligtly different, using uname -a.
MacBook M1:
Darwin macm1 23.4.0 Darwin Kernel Version 23.4.0: Fri Mar 15 00:12:41 PDT 2024; root:xnu-10063.101.17~1/RELEASE_ARM64_T8103 arm64

iMac M3:
Darwin macm3 23.4.0 Darwin Kernel Version 23.4.0: Fri Mar 15 00:11:08 PDT 2024; root:xnu-10063.101.17~1/RELEASE_ARM64_T8122 arm64

We see that the build times differ by one minute and the release is ARM64_T8103 on M1 and ARM64_T8122 on M3. Probably, specialized builds for the target chips.
Here a source code for a test program:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    uint64_t modifier = 2;
    uint64_t data_ia = 0x12345678;
    uint64_t data_ib = 0x12345678;
    uint64_t data_da = 0x12345678;
    uint64_t data_db = 0x12345678;

    printf("PACIA             PACIB             PACDA             PACDB\n");
    printf("%016" PRIX64 "  %016" PRIX64 "  %016" PRIX64 "  %016" PRIX64 "\n", data_ia, data_ib, data_da, data_db);

    asm volatile("pacia %[reg], %[mod]" : [reg] "+r" (data_ia) : [mod] "r" (modifier) : );
    asm volatile("pacib %[reg], %[mod]" : [reg] "+r" (data_ib) : [mod] "r" (modifier) : );
    asm volatile("pacda %[reg], %[mod]" : [reg] "+r" (data_da) : [mod] "r" (modifier) : );
    asm volatile("pacdb %[reg], %[mod]" : [reg] "+r" (data_db) : [mod] "r" (modifier) : );

    printf("%016" PRIX64 "  %016" PRIX64 "  %016" PRIX64 "  %016" PRIX64 "\n", data_ia, data_ib, data_da, data_db);

    asm volatile("autia %[reg], %[mod]" : [reg] "+r" (data_ia) : [mod] "r" (modifier) : );
    asm volatile("autib %[reg], %[mod]" : [reg] "+r" (data_ib) : [mod] "r" (modifier) : );
    asm volatile("autda %[reg], %[mod]" : [reg] "+r" (data_da) : [mod] "r" (modifier) : );
    asm volatile("autdb %[reg], %[mod]" : [reg] "+r" (data_db) : [mod] "r" (modifier) : );

    printf("%016" PRIX64 "  %016" PRIX64 "  %016" PRIX64 "  %016" PRIX64 "\n", data_ia, data_ib, data_da, data_db);
}

Build:
$ cc -arch arm64e pac.c -o pac

Execution on the MacBook M1:
$ ./pac
PACIA             PACIB             PACDA             PACDB
0000000012345678  0000000012345678  0000000012345678  0000000012345678
6C77000012345678  440A800012345678  0007000012345678  0059000012345678
0000000012345678  0000000012345678  0000000012345678  0000000012345678
$ ./pac
PACIA             PACIB             PACDA             PACDB
0000000012345678  0000000012345678  0000000012345678  0000000012345678
6206000012345678  3229800012345678  0075000012345678  0065000012345678
0000000012345678  0000000012345678  0000000012345678  0000000012345678
$ ./pac
PACIA             PACIB             PACDA             PACDB
0000000012345678  0000000012345678  0000000012345678  0000000012345678
E035800012345678  C611800012345678  000B000012345678  005A000012345678
0000000012345678  0000000012345678  0000000012345678  0000000012345678

We see that all 4 PAC keys change in each new process.
Execution on the iMac M3:
$ ./pac
PACIA             PACIB             PACDA             PACDB
0000000012345678  0000000012345678  0000000012345678  0000000012345678
712B800012345678  8333000012345678  0050800012345678  0011000012345678
0000000012345678  0000000012345678  0000000012345678  0000000012345678
$ ./pac
PACIA             PACIB             PACDA             PACDB
0000000012345678  0000000012345678  0000000012345678  0000000012345678
712B800012345678  F264800012345678  0050800012345678  0046000012345678
0000000012345678  0000000012345678  0000000012345678  0000000012345678
$ ./pac
PACIA             PACIB             PACDA             PACDB
0000000012345678  0000000012345678  0000000012345678  0000000012345678
712B800012345678  B43F000012345678  0050800012345678  001B000012345678
0000000012345678  0000000012345678  0000000012345678  0000000012345678

We see that the IA and DA keys are the same in all processes. Only IB and DB change.
I have already written about Arm64 pointer authentication here and here. But this is the first time I see this.

Since running 3rd-party arm64e binaries is not allowed in macOS' default configuration, can you share your applied boot-args? And ideally also the toolchain version (cc -v)? I'm assuming this is all running on the host, not in a VM?

Also, I had a look at your GitHub doc, and several things are wrong there. macOS always boots as arm64e, and system binaries always run with PAC enabled. The restriction only applies to non-Apple binaries. But at the system level, PAC is always enabled and even arm64 processes run with the IB key enabled. Also, Apple Silicon Macs don't have EL3. The last Apple chip to feature EL3 was the A9X. The reason you can't read key registers is a custom ISA extension, I recommend reading this USENIX paper from 2023.

Also, the reason why arm64e processes can't load arm64 libraries isn't "for security", it's because the ABI would be violated. If an arm64e binary were to pass a function pointer to an arm64 library, then the caller would sign the function pointer but the callee would use it as-is, thus crashing because it doesn't expect a signature in the top bits.

This is by design, and is mentioned in the PointerAuthentication.rst document in LLVM:

Key assignments
ARMv8.3 provides four abstract signing keys: IA, IB, DA, and DB. The architecture designates IA and IB for signing code pointers and DA and DB for signing data pointers; this is reinforced by two properties:

The ISA provides instructions that perform combined auth+call and auth+load operations; these instructions can only use the I keys and D keys, respectively.
AArch64's TBI feature can be separately enabled for code pointers (controlling whether indirect-branch instructions ignore those bits) and data pointers (controlling whether memory-access instructions) ignore those bits. If TBI is enabled for a kind of pointer, the sign and auth operations preserve the TBI bits when signing with an associated keys (at the cost of shrinking the number of available signing bits by 8).

arm64e then further subdivides the keys as follows:

The A keys are used for primarily "global" purposes like signing v-tables and function pointers. These keys are sometimes called process-independent or cross-process because on existing OSes they are not changed when changing processes, although this is not a platform guarantee.
The B keys are used for primarily "local" purposes like signing return addresses and frame pointers. These keys are sometimes called process-specific because they are typically different between processes. However, they are in fact shared across processes in one situation: systems which provide fork cannot change these keys in the child process; they can only be changed during exec.


(It is also mentioned in various places in XNU source, but the one in LLVM is the most elaborate.)
What it doesn't specify is why this is being done: the dyld_shared_cache. This >4GB giga-monolith of system libraries that is mapped into every process. There's a whole range of optimisations around that thing, and this is one of them. I was going to write "it's probably more relevant on iOS", but then I remembered that Apple still sells MacBooks with 8GB of RAM, so... it's definitely relevant on macOS as well.
Now, the dyld_shared_cache consists of three types of segments: executable (TEXT_EXEC), readonly (TEXT, DATA_CONST, LINKEDIT), and writeable (DATA).
The executable segments have to be codesigned, and are thus immutable and can share their backing memory across all processes no matter what.
Both the readonly and the writeable segments can contain pointers though, which means that those pages will have to be modified by the dynamic linker, which of course triggers an unshare of the backing memory. Doing this for more than 1GB of memory for every process is going to be very, very, VERY resource-intensive.
But what if that didn't have to be the case? What if, instead of having the dynamic linker fault all of those pages in, we'd just have it register the linking info with the kernel, and then the kernel could apply that individually to each page as it is faulted in. And before pointer authentication was a thing, placing the dyld_shared_cache at the same address in every process was even enough to make all of those pointers be the same across processes, so all of those readonly pages could be shared again, and even writeable pages would start out with a shared CoW copy! Now that we have pointer authentication, that is all going down the drain... unless of course, the keys used to sign those pointers would happen to be the same across processes.
And here we are. Page-in linking is a thing in XNU, the dyld_shared_cache is at the same address in (almost) all processes, the pointers in its segments are signed with the A keys, and so those keys are shared across processes.
Now, there are some exceptions. Processes with the com.apple.pac.shared_region_id entitlement will get their own copy of the shared cache, and their own A keys based on the value of that entitlement. This is used for processes that are commonly the target of remote code execution exploits, such as WebContent, iMessage/BlastDoor, etc. If you gain code execution in one of those processes, then you will not be able to sign pointers for any other process.

So why is it not like this in OP's test on the M1 system?

@NateEldredge good question, I missed that bit. But since running 3rd-party arm64e binaries is not allowed in the default configuration of macOS, the question actually needs more information.

Thank you all for your contributions. Unfortunately, none provides an answer to the original and only question: why does the same version of macOS behaves differently on M1 and M3 chips.
Some responses to requests from @Siguza:

can you share your applied boot-args? And ideally also the toolchain version (cc -v)? I'm assuming this is all running on the host, not in a VM?

The boot flags are -arm64e_preview_abi and system integrity is disabled (csrutil disable under recovery OS). Both are required to run arm64e execs and unmute PAC instructions.
The compiler is Apple clang version 15.0.0 (clang-1500.3.9.4), the latest version of xcode command line tools. Note that this is irrelevant regarding the difference of behaviour between PACIA and PACIB, especially since my test directly uses the PACxx instructions from asm directives. The compiler code generation does not matter.
And yes, this is the native host macOS, not a VM.

Also, I had a look at your GitHub doc, and several things are wrong there. macOS always boots as arm64e, and system binaries always run with PAC enabled. The restriction only applies to non-Apple binaries. But at the system level, PAC is always enabled and even arm64 processes run with the IB key enabled.

I understand that you "had a look" but you did not read it. My paper exactly says the same thing as you.
Except one thing: "the restriction only applies to non-Apple binaries" is incorrect. This is not a matter of Apple vs. non-Apple, this is matter of location in the file system. The restriction applies only outside the part of the file system which is protected by the system integrity. In this part of the paper, we can see that /bin/echo is an arm64e "Apple binary". It works when run from /bin, which is under protection of the system integrity. Just copy this "Apple binary" in your home directory and run it, it fails with SIGKILL (in the default macOS configuration). So, this is not a matter of "Apple binary".

Also, Apple Silicon Macs don't have EL3. The last Apple chip to feature EL3 was the A9X. The reason you can't read key registers is a custom ISA extension, I recommend reading this USENIX paper from 2023.

I will read it, thanks for the pointer.
I will check the "custom ISA extension" but it cannot be this only. There is a way to read/write the PAC key registers because each process has its own set of 5 PAC keys for user mode and 5 other PAC keys for kernel mode. Each time there is a process context switch, the 5 PAC keys are modified. Each time there is a user/kernel mode, EL0/EL1, switch, the 5 PAC kays are also updated (the Arm architecture defines only one set of 5 PAC keys for all EL, not a set of registers per EL, unlike a few other system registers which have _EL0, _EL1, etc counterparts). So, somehow, the kernel has a way to read/write the PAC registers, maybe delegating the operation to some more privileged EL. Maybe, or maybe some other way.
Please note that my paper clearly separates facts and observations on one hand and speculations on the other hand, speculations on how this may be implemented. The usage of EL3 was explicitly marked as "speculation".
When using a Linux or Windows VM (I have both on the M1), it is quite possible to read and write the PAC key registers from a kernel module. I tried. There is still the possibility that the hypervisor traps the read / write operations on key registers through configuration of HCR_EL2 or HFGRTR_EL2 / HFGWTR_EL2 and then emulates the key R/W and all PAC operations. Possible but probably unlikely.

Also, the reason why arm64e processes can't load arm64 libraries isn't "for security", it's because the ABI would be violated. If an arm64e binary were to pass a function pointer to an arm64 library, then the caller would sign the function pointer but the callee would use it as-is, thus crashing because it doesn't expect a signature in the top bits.

I disagree with that. Totally. Technically, the incompatibility of ABI between arm64 and arm64e is not a problem. It is solved by muting the PAC instructions from SCTLR_EL1. For instance, calling an arm64e library from an arm64 exec is allowed and works, even though the very same ABI incompatibility is present. So, technically, the kernel could allow arm64/amr64e mixtures in any direction. The fact that arm64 exec -> arm64e lib is allowed and not the opposite makes sense for security reasons, not for technical ABI compatibility reasons.

This is by design, and is mentioned in the PointerAuthentication.rst document in LLVM:

The LLVM doc is very clear, very interesting. It was one of my first readings and it is referenced in my papers. However, what it explains has nothing to do with the difference of behaviour between M1 and M3 chips in the "A" keys management. The paper explains how the PAC keys are used in the generated code, not how and why the operating system should use same or different keys in different processes.
Please read the original question. The problem is about the behaviour of the operating system, not the CPU, not the compiler.

Using the same code and same binary on M1 and M3 chips, same version of macOS, different IA and DA key management.
Using explicit PACIA and PACIB instructions from asm directives, meaning testing the CPU, not the compiler.

All the rest of your explanation is interesting but the fact that is works differently on M1 chips makes it unfortunately irrelevant.

But since running 3rd-party arm64e binaries is not allowed in the default configuration of macOS, the question actually needs more information.

This is precisely why I posted that question here! To get more information if anyone had any. I see that we are all at the same level of information for now.

The USENIX paper should clear up your doubts about how PAC works. In short, the key registers don't hold the effective keys, but are merely one input that is mixed with other things to arrive at the effective keys. Among those is an "extra key" register that is used to diversify between exception levels. And in "Apple PA mode", the hardware allows writing the key registers, but not reading from them. And if Apple's custom PA mode is disabled, the PAC key registers can be read from as usual.

The reason why Apple binaries get killed if you copy them elsewhere is not because they're arm64e, but because of launch constraints, which are tied to trustcache entries. But there exist arm64e binaries outside of the readonly root volume, e.g. /Library/Apple/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDevice.framework/Versions/A/AppleMobileDeviceHelper.app/Contents/MacOS/AppleMobileDeviceHelper  - that one can be copied to /tmp or anywhere else, and will run from there. Because it's an Apple-signed binary.

And your "solution" to the arm64/arm64e incompatibility problem doesn't work because the kernel doesn't know ahead of time all the libraries that will be loaded into the process - after all, dlopen exists. And PAC cannot be switched off after process creation because by then, signed pointers will have been written to memory. So that decision has to be made solely based on whether the main binary of the process supports PAC or not. The kernel could speculatively run everything with PAC off (or you can force that manually by patching the Mach-O header), but then what would be the point of PAC.

Your question looks like you don't understand why the A keys are set up with a static value, but the PACIA/DA results, which are generated with the same inputs, vary across different processes.
Maybe you can check out this USENIX paper or this Blackhat talk (I recommend the talk, and you can jump to the finding section to get what you want) to know how PAC works on Apple Silicon.
The value of REAL A KEY, which is used for generating the authentication code in user space, is not the static one you found. An 'extra key' will xor with the A KEY (the static one) to get the user-space REAL A KEY. The 'extra key' is set up with a per-process value, so you get different results generated using A KEY among different processes.

I have read the USENIX paper (and you are apparently one of the authors, so let me say that you did and excellent job). My question is different. It is about the difference of behaviour between the M1 and M3. Your paper is about the M1. I have had an M1 for two years and made a lot of tests on PAC. I know the behaviour of the M1. Now, I have a M3 and I see a distinct behaviour. That is my question.

@Thierry Lelegard Oh, I see. Sorry for my misunderstanding. Thanks for sharing this info. Do you also see this difference when running an earlier version of kernel? Actually I did noticed some checks when XNU kernel sets up the PA keys, which leads to different key management. Maybe that's the answer about why you see this distinct behaviour. But I didn't test on M3 and don't know why they did it in this way yet.
